# How to set a Message Handler programmatically in Spring Cloud AWS SQS?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

maybe someone has an idea to my following problem:

I am currently on a project, where i want to use the AWS SQS with Spring Cloud integration. For the receiver part i want to provide a API, where a user can register a "message handler" on a queue, which is an interface and will contain the user's business logic, e.g.

```
MyAwsSqsReceiver receiver = new MyAwsSqsReceiver();
receiver.register("a-queue-name", new MessageHandler(){
  @Override
  public void handle(String message){
    //... business logic for the received message
  }
});
```

I found examples, e.g. 
https://codemason.me/2016/03/12/amazon-aws-sqs-with-spring-cloud/
and read the docu
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_sqs_support

But the only thing i found there to "connect" a functionality for processing a incoming message is a annotation on a method, e.g. `@SqsListener` or `@MessageMapping`.

These annotations are fixed to a certain queue-name, though. So now i am at a loss, how to dynamically "connect" my provided "MessageHandler" (from my API) to the incoming message for the specified queuename.

In the Config the example there is a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, which gets a `QueueMessageHandler` set, but this QueueMessageHandler does not seem 
to be the right place to set my handler or to override its methods and provide my own subclass of `QueueMessageHandler`.

I already did something like this with the Spring Amqp integration and RabbitMq and thought, that it would be also similar here with AWS SQS.

Does anyone have an idea, how to accomplish this?

thx + bye,
Ximon

**EDIT**:

I found, that Spring JMS could actually do that, e.g. *www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/02/aws-sqs-spring-jms-integration.html*. Does anybody know, what consequences using JMS protocol has here, good or bad?

Comment: hello, do you found a solution for you problem? i have the same issue and looking for solution. thx

Comment: Try the solution I have posted @user1167253

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same issue.

I am trying to go in an unusual way where I set up an Aws client bean at build time and then instead of using sqslistener annotation to consume from the specific queue I use the scheduled annotation which I can programmatically **pool** (each 10 secs in my case) from which queue I want to consume.

I did the example that iterates over queues defined in properties and then consumes from each one.

Client Bean:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public AmazonSQSAsync awsSqsClient() {
    return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1.getName())
            .build();
}
```

Consumer:

```
// injected in the constructor
private final AmazonSQSAsync awsSqsClient;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
public void pool() {
    properties.getSqsQueues()
            .forEach(queue -> {
                val receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(queue)
                        .withWaitTimeSeconds(10)
                        .withMaxNumberOfMessages(10);

                // reading the messages
                val result = awsSqsClient.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest);
                val sqsMessages = result.getMessages();
                log.info("Received Message on queue {}: message = {}", queue, sqsMessages.toString());

                // deleting the messages
                sqsMessages.forEach(message -> {
                    val deleteMessageRequest = new DeleteMessageRequest(queue, message.getReceiptHandle());
                    awsSqsClient.deleteMessage(deleteMessageRequest);
                });
            });
}
```

Just to clarify, in my case, I need multiple queues, one for each tenant, with the queue URL for each one passed in a property file. Of course, in your case, you could get the queue names from another source, maybe a ThreadLocal which has the queues you have created in runtime.

If you wish, you can also try the JMS approach where you create message consumers and add a listener to each one you wish (See the doc [Aws Jms documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/getting-started.html)).

Answer (score -1):

When we do Spring and SQS we use the spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging.

Then just create a Listener class

```
@Component
public class MyListener {

@SQSListener(value="myqueue")
public void listen(MyMessageType message) {
//process the message
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for answering. Unfortunately, this is not what i intended. In my use-case i don't know the name of the queue - it is created dynamically e.g. by a API "createQueue(String name)" call. After that i would like to set a listener dynamically.

Comment: Oh okay that wasn't clear to me from the question. I was just trying to give you a very Springy way to do it with very little code. I like the way Spring wraps the AWS libraries, but in our use case all Queues are predefined so you can just inject the queue name with SPEL.

That approach won't work for your case as when you stand up the app and Spring tries to stand up that component it won't know the queue name yet (even if you set a env variable with it and used SPEL to access that).